# FB login not working on iOS after upgrade to FB SDK 14.1.0

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine

We are using Unity 2019.4.15f1.After upgrading to FB SDK 14.1.0 when clicking on login with facebook button the iOS app is freezing and crashing.

Original:
I can see this in the logs:

```
Sep 21 15:29:21 iPhone MyProject(UnityFramework)[15154] <Notice>: Uncaught exception: 

InvalidOperationException: fb0 is not registered as a URL scheme. Please add it in your Info.plist
(
   0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019076529c 6B22DD81-3585-3BE6-BC77-BA19810EC0F2 + 627356
   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001a9495744 objc_exception_throw + 60
   2   FBSDKCoreKit                        0x00000001056dd3bc -[FBSDKInternalUtility validateFacebookReservedURLSchemes] + 0
   3   FBSDKLoginKit                       0x0000000105a99624 $s13FBSDKLoginKit12LoginManagerC15logInParameters13configuration12loggingToken20authenticationMethodSDyS2SGSgAA0C13ConfigurationCSg_SSSgSStF + 372
   4   FBSDKLoginKit                       0x0000000105a97544 $s13FBSDKLoginKit12LoginManagerC19performBrowserLogIn33_C218275A97333B874EDDFE627110566CLL7handleryySb_s5Error_pSgtcSg_tF + 1216
   5   FBSDKLoginKit                       0x0000000105aa1b00 $s13FBSDKLoginKit12LoginManagerC5logIn33_C218275A97333B874EDDFE627110566CLL11permissions7handleryShyAA12FBPermissionCG_yAA0cdC6Resul
```

This is what we have in our `info.plist` file .

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
   <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
         <string>fb***************</string>
      </array>
   </dict>
</array>
```

We have this `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in our `info.plist` file too:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>fbapi</string>
      <string>fbapi20130214</string>
      <string>fbapi20130410</string>
      <string>fbapi20130702</string>
      <string>fbapi20131010</string>
      <string>fbapi20131219</string>
      <string>fbapi20140410</string>
      <string>fbapi20140116</string>
      <string>fbapi20150313</string>
      <string>fbapi20150629</string>
      <string>fbapi20160328</string>
      <string>fbauth</string>
      <string>fbauth2</string>
      <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
    </array>
```

UPDATE:
After adding `fb0` to `CFBundleURLSchemes` like this:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
   <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
         <string>fb0</string>
         <string>fb***************</string>
      </array>
   </dict>
</array>
```

The app isn't crashing anymore, however it shows "Sorry, something went wrong" webpage from Facebook.

**Resolution**:

I finally found out that after updating the FB SDK, the FacebookSettings.asset file got corrupted and all the app IDs were gone.

I had to fix that by re-copying the `FacebookSettings.asset` file and adding the app IDs again.

And I removed the `fb0` entry from `CFBundleURLSchemes` as it was clearly not needed and is a default value inside the FB SDK itself.

I am updating it here so that if someone else faces this problem it might help them.

Comment: From the [upgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/upgrading-7.x) "Minimum supported Unity version is bumped to 2019.4.39f1 for Android, iOS or Windows. Minimum supported Unity version is bumped to 2021.3.4f1 if targeting webgl." You may need to update Unity. Worth a try to see if it helps.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Due to some infrastructure limitations. I can't upgrade to `2019.4.39f1` just yet. We don't have much more use case other than login, and I am seeing success for Android already, it's just that iOS is not working.

Comment: I assume you use source control. Clone to a new directory, upgrade the project, see if it works. Nothing lost if it doesn't but if it does you know of a solution.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for taking the time to helping me out. Turns out FacebookSettings.asset file was corrupted somehow and all of the app IDs were gone. That was causing the problem. It seems to be working now.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: The FacebookSettings.asset file is annoying. :( Whenever I have to update the pugin I delete everything since they rename files sometimes then install the new one and look at the diff in git to copy over all the stuff that went missing. If the file structure didn't change you can usually get away with just reverting to the git copy and fixing the guid link so Unity recognizes it. Still a mess, and the most likely plugin to cause issues. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution**:

I finally found out that after updating the FB SDK, the FacebookSettings.asset file got corrupted and all the app IDs were gone.

I had to fix that by re-copying the `FacebookSettings.asset` file and adding the app IDs again.

And I removed the `fb0` entry from `CFBundleURLSchemes` as it was clearly not needed and is a default value inside the FB SDK itself.

I am updating it here so that if someone else faces this problem it might help them.